# PHP online shopping store

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I'm developing an online shopping store but I don't know what's the best way to ensure a product is available during the time the customer does checkout and really pays out.

Let's say, I have 2 items XX, and I add 1 to my cart, when should I pre-reserve that item in my database? When the client clicks checkout and the paypal link is generated? And if the client never pays it, how do I turn that item available again? And if the client waits too long to pay?

I was looking for some answers how this process is done.

## UPDATE

I'm currently doing it (adding the item to the reserved item list) only when I generate the paypal link so the customer can pay...and I add it to the reserved item database. Here are my questions? How do I set a timout in paypal so the link is only valid for X minutes? How to delete that item from database it the time is over X minutes? with a cron job and php file?
My problem is someone reserving and item and never paying and that item stays reserved forever or reserving and item and the payout takes too long that someone else buys it..

## UPDATE 2

The real item are a local SQL server database and the store works with a web based mysql server, so I have to sync the 2 of them, because I cannot modify the sql server database, I can only add an order there when it's final.

Comment: This is part of *your* design work. There's no "right answer". But I've seen some sites reserve an item for half an hour, giving you ample time to check out before returning it to the store inventory (and auto-cancelling your order). Others will do a final check for availability when you check out, and apologise if you were too slow. Pick a way that works for you!

Comment: It's a complicated question and their is no absolute answer. You have to make choses before considering technical issues: **when** should i reserve the item. **how long** your customer can pay, **is it a problem** if you have to say to a customer that the item is no longer available just before paying, etc...

Comment: Some places let negative inventory occur, and then tell the user that there will be a shipping delay because of high demand, and give them an option to cancel their order. If it happens rarely this is probably an OK solution.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to achieve this, according to how do you want your system work.
One way is to create a table for the shopping cart that holds all information of the customers' shopping cart. In addition, you can assign a timeout for each shopping cart. You should not reduce the availability of the item directly in the database when a customer add an item into the shopping cart. Instead, the availability displayed on the webpage should be calculated from the tem availability - the quantity of this item in all shopping cart.

Comment: you can use the **session** or define timeout in the shopping cart table.

Comment: if you define the timeout for the cart, you don't need to be worried about cleaning up the shopping cart. if you want to calculate the availability of an item, you get the availability of the item in the **products** table, for example, and subtract the number of item reserved in the shopping cart that are not expired (i.e. not timed out). You can clean up the shopping cart table manually or by a scheduled job.